# How can I match one individual's survey responses across time to form a panel dataset?

Tags: python, pandas, merge, survey, panel-data

I am working with survey data in which respondents were interviewed twice: once initially and once six to eight months later. Each month, new interviewees are contacted, resulting in a rotating panel structure. How can I match an individual to his/her previous interview in Python using the following information:

```
   CASEID  YYYYMM  ID IDPREV  DATEPR   INCOME
1       2  198706   2    382  198612    12500
2       3  198706   3      4  198612     2500
3       4  198706   4     67  198612    27500
4       5  198706   5    134  198612    12500
5       6  198706   6    193  198612    22500
```

So, the first line states that the individual's previous answers to the survey are contained on the line where the previous date is 198612 (Dec. 1986) and the ID is 382. How can I match these responses using the information that I have to create a panel dataset of the following form:

```
   CASEID  YYYYMM  ID IDPREV  DATEPR   INCOME
1     463  198612 382      -       -    12000
     1856  198706   2    382  198612    12500
2      97  198612   4      -       -     3500 
     1857  198706   3      4  198612     2500
3     164  198612  67      -       -    25000
     1858  198706   4     67  198612    27500
4     289  198612 134      -       -    12500
     1859  198706   5    134  198612    12500
5     323  198612 193      -       -    22500
     1860  198706   6    193  198612    22500
```

I have looked into the "merge" documentation for pandas and have tried a couple of different ways of matching the dates and IDs by indexing them, but cannot seem to get the panel data structure.

Comment: Were you able to get this to work after all?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response. Unfortunately, it looks like implementing the second step results in a dataframe with no values (other than the headers). I've been trying to work on a solution to this that is less obtuse than creating two different dataframes (one with individuals who have previously responded and one with individuals who have not) and merging those. Any additional suggestions would be helpful, as would pointing out any obvious mistakes that I might be making.

Comment: You could get an empty `DataFrame`, assuming the names of the merge columns are correct and there are actual matches, if the data types do not correspond - one numeric, one string, or datetime. Take a look at `.info()` for both `df` for starters. Are the commands below clear or do you need any clarification what they are supposed to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with:

```
   CASEID  YYYYMM   ID  IDPREV    DATEPR  INCOME
0     463  198612  382     NaN       NaN   12000
1    1856  198706    2   382.0  198612.0   12500
2      97  198612    4     NaN       NaN    3500
3    1857  198706    3     4.0  198612.0    2500
4     164  198612   67     NaN       NaN   25000
5    1858  198706    4    67.0  198612.0   27500
6     289  198612  134     NaN       NaN   12500
7    1859  198706    5   134.0  198612.0   12500
8     323  198612  193     NaN       NaN   22500
9    1860  198706    6   193.0  198612.0   22500
```

You could combine the two observations by merging:

```
combined = pd.merge(df, df, left_on=['YYYYMM', 'ID'], right_on=['DATEPR', 'IDPREV'], suffixes=['_1', '_2'])

   CASEID_1  YYYYMM_1  ID_1  IDPREV_1  DATEPR_1  INCOME_1  CASEID_2  YYYYMM_2  \
0       463    198612   382       NaN       NaN     12000      1856    198706   
1        97    198612     4       NaN       NaN      3500      1857    198706   
2       164    198612    67       NaN       NaN     25000      1858    198706   
3       289    198612   134       NaN       NaN     12500      1859    198706   
4       323    198612   193       NaN       NaN     22500      1860    198706   

   ID_2  IDPREV_2  DATEPR_2  INCOME_2  
0     2     382.0  198612.0     12500  
1     3       4.0  198612.0      2500  
2     4      67.0  198612.0     27500  
3     5     134.0  198612.0     12500  
4     6     193.0  198612.0     22500
```

from where you could select the `columns` you need, or while merging:

```
combined = pd.merge(df.loc[:, ['CASEID', 'YYYYMM', 'ID', 'INCOME']], df,
                    left_on=['YYYYMM', 'ID'], right_on=['DATEPR', 'IDPREV'], suffixes=['_1', '_2'])


   CASEID_1  YYYYMM_1  ID_1  INCOME_1  CASEID_2  YYYYMM_2  ID_2  IDPREV  \
0       463    198612   382     12000      1856    198706     2   382.0   
1        97    198612     4      3500      1857    198706     3     4.0   
2       164    198612    67     25000      1858    198706     4    67.0   
3       289    198612   134     12500      1859    198706     5   134.0   
4       323    198612   193     22500      1860    198706     6   193.0   

     DATEPR  INCOME_2  
0  198612.0     12500  
1  198612.0      2500  
2  198612.0     27500  
3  198612.0     12500  
4  198612.0     22500
```

You could form a panel from here:

```
combined = combined.reset_index().set_index('index')
df1 = combined.loc[:, ['CASEID_1', 'YYYYMM_1', 'ID_1', 'INCOME_1']]
df1.rename(columns={col: col[:-2] for col in df1.columns}, inplace=True)
df2 = combined.loc[:, ['CASEID_2', 'YYYYMM_2', 'ID_2', 'INCOME_2']]
df2.rename(columns={col: col[:-2] for col in df2.columns}, inplace=True)

panel = pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_index()

       CASEID  YYYYMM   ID  INCOME
index                             
0         463  198612  382   12000
0        1856  198706    2   12500
1          97  198612    4    3500
1        1857  198706    3    2500
2         164  198612   67   25000
2        1858  198706    4   27500
3         289  198612  134   12500
3        1859  198706    5   12500
4         323  198612  193   22500
4        1860  198706    6   22500
```